# change name of select_year field

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a select_year in my code:

```
select_year(Date.today, :start_year => -3.years.from_now.year, :end_year => 3.years.from_now.year)
```

The html renders: name="date[year]"

I want it to be: name="year"

I tried to add

```
:prefix => "year"
```

but it gives me name="year[year]"

How can I get just "year"?

Comment: have you tired `name: 'year'`?

Comment: Doesn't change anything. Maybe I need to put some parenthesis here? I am not sure where.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found how to do it:

```
select_year(Date.today, :start_year => -3.years.from_now.year,
:end_year => 3.years.from_now.year, :prefix => "year", :discard_type => true)
```

maybe it'll be useful to someone else.

Answer (score 1):

This also works

select_year

```
select_year(Date.today, {:start_year => Date.today.year-3, :end_year =>  Date.today.year+3}, id: 'year', name: 'year')
```

select_month

```
select_month(Date.today, {use_month_numbers: true}, id: 'month', name: 'month')
```

( replace Date.today with nil if you don't want a default month selected )

Comment: This should be the correct answer. 

To clarify `id` and `name` attributes need to come in the second hash as they are HTML_options: `select_year(date, options = {}, html_options = {})`

Answer (score -1):

The method `select_year` is meant to be used to created a full-date field with multiple selects for day, month and year.  Therefore, it uses a prefix to group these fields together. As it looks, you can *not* use it without a prefix.

The solution is to create your own helper method.

Comment: See my answer. It is possible